# Can't read from local SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi, I am having trouble reading from a embedded SQLite database in my project.

I want to get the data from one activity to another and displaying it in TextView.

Here is my database tools class:

```
public class myDBTools extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.appscan5/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "productlist";

private static SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

public myDBTools(Context applicationContext) {
    super(applicationContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    myDatabase= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME,null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public static HashMap<String, String> getProductInfo(String id) {

    HashMap<String, String> productMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE _id='" + id + "'";

    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // move to the first row of dataBase
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            productMap.put("NumberId", cursor.getString(0));
            productMap.put("BarcodeId", cursor.getString(1));
            productMap.put("ProductName", cursor.getString(2));
            productMap.put("Calories", cursor.getString(3));
            productMap.put("Protein", cursor.getString(4));
            productMap.put("Carbohydrates", cursor.getString(5));
            productMap.put("Fats", cursor.getString(6));
            productMap.put("Grams", cursor.getString(7));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return productMap;
}
}
```

Here is how I use it in another activity:

```
myDBTools mydbTools = new myDBTools(this);
HashMap<String, String> productMap = mydbTools.getProductInfo(id);
```

Comment: Just something extra, you may not want to use `SELECT *`, if any of your structure changes later it could break you getting the information out based off those positions. It'd be better to use something like `SELECT numberId, barcodeId, productName` etc

Answer (score 1):

You will need to open the database first.

```
mydbTools.open();
```

put above line into your oncreate, and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You must `Open` database before any Operation: create open method

```
// ---opens the database---
public myDBTools open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

And must `Close` database after operation completed. create close method

```
// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

Now, after creating your `myDBTools object` called this `Open` and `Close` methods like

```
myDBTools mydbTools = new myDBTools(this);
mydbTools.open();

//All the operations related to database
mydbTools.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a lot of trouble using the database with SQLite. It seems i have been creating a database but havent been copying the content of my database file to the newly created database using SQLiteOpenHelper.

In the end i had a database with no tables in it and dus i couldnt execute a select query and here is where i got an error:

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE _id='" + id + "'";
 Cursor cursor = myDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

This is my full working code so far of the database class:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String TAG = MyDatabase.class.getName();

private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.appscan5/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "productlist.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
private final Context myContext;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    this.myContext = context;
    Log.v("log_tag", "DBPath: " + DB_PATH);
    // File f=getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
    if (dbExist) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "database does exist");
    } else {
        Log.v("log_tag", "database does not exist");

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path 
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database. 
        db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();           
        db_Read.close();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   " + dbFile.exists());

    return dbFile.exists();
}

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

    return myDataBase != null;
}


@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null) myDataBase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //When i use this createQuery i create a database and don't get an error but the database is empty.

    // String createQuery =
    // "CREATE TABLE products (numberId INTEGER NOT NULL, barcodeID TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, calories INTEGER NOT NULL, protein INTEGER,carbohydrates INTEGER, fats INTEGER, grams INTEGER, sodium INTEGER, fibre INTEGER)";
    // db.execSQL(createQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Upgrading database, this will drop database and recreate.");
}

public HashMap<String, String> getProductInfo(String id) {

    HashMap<String, String> productMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    openDataBase();


    // HERE I GET AN EROR ( NO SUCH TABLE )
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE barcodeId='" + id + "'";

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM products";


    Cursor myCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (!myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.w("debug", "No tables!");
    } else
        Log.w("Done", "Table is here");


    do {

        productMap.put("NumberId", myCursor.getString(0));
        productMap.put("BarcodeId", myCursor.getString(1));
        productMap.put("ProductName", myCursor.getString(2));
        productMap.put("Calories", myCursor.getString(3));
        productMap.put("Protein", myCursor.getString(4));
        productMap.put("Carbohydrates", myCursor.getString(5));
        productMap.put("Fats", myCursor.getString(6));
        productMap.put("Grams", myCursor.getString(7));
        productMap.put("Sodium", myCursor.getString(8));
        productMap.put("Fibre", myCursor.getString(9));


    } while (myCursor.moveToNext());



    close();
    return productMap;


    // My second query here fails, since the database contains no tables.
}

}
```

Here is how i use it in code :

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(this);
try {
    myDB.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

HashMap<String, String> productMap =myDB.getProductInfo(id);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not quite shure is this the best way to use the MyDatabase class. If some one has a better idea of using it please share with an explanation why.

Cheers!